# "Is my answer right?" questions

Tags: discussion, questions

I have come across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35286318/relational-database-design-for-online-store) in a review. In a departure from usual homework questions, this one is a homework assignment along with proposed solutions, and asks whether they are correct.

Is this a valid question for Stack Overflow?

From the ["What's On Topic?" Help Center page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

> Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

There is a summary of the work done to solve the problem - the proposed answers. But the asked isn't having any specific difficulty in solving it, so there's nothing to describe.

On the other hand, the question seems to be the programming equivalent of "Proof read this for me", which I know is first on [the list of *English Language & Usage Stack Exchange*'s off-topic questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) - is there a similar policy here that I haven't noticed before now?

Comment: Putting aside the issue of whether "have I solved this problem correctly?" questions are on topic or not, that one is just a bad question plain and simple.

Comment: *Can someone check problems 1, 2, 3, and 4 for me and see if they are done correctly or if they need any changes to be done.* Still looks like a usual homework question to me. Proposed answers are images in external links, unexploitable. That is indeed a bad question IMHO.

Comment: AKA 'compile, build, test, debug my homework code for me'.  No thanks.

Comment: First answer, accepted: "Yes.".  Second answer, more upvotes than accepted answer: "No."

Comment: I think "why isn't my code working?" would be an acceptable close reason for such "is my code working?" questions.

Answer (score 49):

I would vote to close as Unclear, Too Broad or Opinion-based.

"Please review my design" is all of the above. It doesn't pose a specific question.

Comment: *Please review my design* => Sounds like it would fit on [CodeReview.se]

Comment: @Thomas no, phrased as such it still is way too unspecific for Code Review.

Comment: @Thomas "Here is my code that accomplishes _X_ correctly, to the best of my knowledge" is the standard of quality required for Code Review. If a question meets that standard, then we can discuss the code and its design. However, just a design without a concrete implementation would be off-topic on Code Review.

Comment: @200_success & CodeCaster thank you guys for enlarging my knowledge of Code Review requirements

Comment: 100% agree for this particular question, but I have also seen questions (mostly Big-O lately) where the OP presents an algorithm, presents his take on the Big-O behavior along with *specific reasoning* and asks whether his conclusions are correct. That type of question seems very reasonable to me because it shows research effort, shows detailed steps taken in the analysis and hopefully will be useful to others studying similar algorithms.

Answer (score -8):

I think the problem with this questions is, that the pupil/student does not understand for what school/university is for: learn things by doing them and sometimes failing at doing them. This is how our human brain works. And the teacher is there to correct the mistakes and show proper solutions.

I would write that as a reason to close such a question.

I am right? ;)

Comment: My personal stance is that it has far less to do with not understanding than with not *caring* -- the perspective of having one's work done by others for free is just too strong. This is indeed how our human brain works. It doesn't mean we should be okay with that.

Comment: this is not a valid criticism: you are criticising the question by criticising the user that posed the question.